# Github PR does not show details when the status is "Some checks haven’t completed yet"

Tags: jenkins, github

The details link is available only after PR fails or passes. Is there a way to show details link when the status is "Some checks haven’t completed yet" when the jenkins job is running but not completed yet? Is there a way to report the in progress status back to GitHub pr?

Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When a status check reports itself through the API, it can register a URL for details.  However, in the state you've shown at the top, the status check hasn't reported anything to GitHub yet, and as a consequence GitHub has nothing to show you.

This is likely an issue with Jenkins or your Jenkins configuration that prevents it from reporting an in-progress state to GitHub.  There is documentation online, including [a tutorial](https://applitools.com/blog/how-to-update-jenkins-build-status-in-github-pull-requests-step-by-step-tutorial), that can tell you how to properly configure Jenkins to integrate with GitHub.  That tutorial shows an example of an in-progress state, so theoretically this should work if properly configured.

Comment: Using BlueOcean to trigger pr on the git repo. The tutorial above does not use BlueOcean. Using BlueOcean is there a way to report the in progress status back to GitHub pr?

Comment: I unfortunately don't know.  I've not used Blue Ocean.

Comment: no problem, thanks for your inout. I will post here if I find a solution using blue ocean.